# ESRI Javascript - Dynamically Create Points from Non Spatialized JSON Using Lat/Longs

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, json

I am working on application that needs to make use of a non spatial data set. The data is maintained by the group responsible for the installation of the asset item and thus it makes sense to pull from them rather than keep track of a second data set for spatial solutions. I am able to send a request to an API that queries the database and returns an array of JSON. The objects look as follows:

```
[
    {
        attribute01:value01,
        attribute02:value02,
        ......
        Lattitude:lattitude,
        Longitude:longitude1
    }, 
    {
        attribute01:value01,
        attribute02:value02,
        ......
        Lattitude:lattitude,
        Longitude:longitude1
    }
]
```

What I would like to do is dynamically create the points from this Lat/Long data as well as maintain the other attributes in the response object. I do not require just the points mapped, but rather  I would like to be able to interact with the points in a same manner as I would a feature layer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a FeatureLayer via a FeatureCollection, which is essentially just all your data, with a schema defined. You pass your FeatureCollection instead of the FeatureLayer URL:

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, {
    showLabels: true
});
```

Helpful links:

- [FeatureLayer Constructor from FeatureCollection](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#featurelayer2)
- [FeatureSet](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featureset-amd.html)
- [Feature Layer via FeatureCollection Sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_featureCollection.html)

Comment: It is unclear to me as to how the lat/longs will get plotted in my case. The examples seem to assume I am using JSON from an ArcGIS Server REST endpoint.

Comment: Loop through your JSON object, transforming it from the current schema to a JSON object that follows FeatureSet schema, then with that new JSON object create a new FeatureLayer using that JSON and the layerDefinition: http://i.imgur.com/G0PtIpR.png